# Reference a PCL from Shared Project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created my Android/iOS Xamarin Forms app as a Shared Project. Now I want to add a PCL to handle all the connections with an API. Is this possible? So what I want is to reference the PCL from the main SP and not from the iOS/Android subprojects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Shared Project doesn't have it's own references.  It inherits it's environment, including references, from whatever parent project it is contained within at build time.  Adding the PCL reference to the parent iOS/Android project should allow the shared project to use the PCL classes.